# Close DialogFragment returning to Activity with onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm having a problem to closing a DialogFragment  and returning to the onActivityResult of Activity.

Below is my code that calls the DialogFragment.

```
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("cliente", hashtableFiltros.get("cliente"));
            args.putString("produto", hashtableFiltros.get("produto"));
            args.putString("dataInicio", hashtableFiltros.get("dataInicio"));
            args.putString("dataFim", hashtableFiltros.get("dataFim"));
            args.putInt("valorMin", Integer.parseInt(hashtableFiltros.get("valorMin")));
            args.putInt("valorMax", Integer.parseInt(hashtableFiltros.get("valorMax")));
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FiltroPedidos dialogFragment = new FiltroPedidos();
            dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
            dialogFragment.show(fm, "FiltroPedidos");
```

After clicking on the PositiveButton of the DialogFragment it would have to a requestCode and returning to the Activity.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PedidosFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra("cliente", "");
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

Returning to this is onActivityResult within the Activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null) {
        if (requestCode == 5) {

    }   
}
```

What could be wrong? Because it closes the DialogFragment but does not go to the onActivityResult.

Comment: Please write in English

Comment: Wellcome Leonardo! I speak Spanish, but I think I get what you meant. When starting the activity for result with startActivityForResult(intent, 5) you are not setting the Activity you want to open. Activity for result is used when want to go from activity A to B, and expect a result from B. If you want to get data from the dialog, then you don't want to use startActivityForResult

Comment: Sebasira, I tried to start the intent and it did not work the same.

Comment: If you want to communicate between an activity and its fragment (also a dialog fragment) you should define an interface inside your activity and implement the interface inside the fragment, take a look to this simple example: https://github.com/ngallazzi/ActivityToFragmentCommunicationExample